# Spearman Correlation from 'two-ways'

Tags: ranking, mean, spearman-rho

I have two data sets where I am comparing where an object in the first data set, ranks in the second data set and vice versa. This leads to the assumption that the data set being compared against is the 'true' data set and thus has a perfect order.

It looks like this when comparing B against A:

A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

B = [2 1 17 4 5 6 9 3 7 14]

Spearman's rho = .5030

It look like this when comparing A against B:

A = [2 1 8 4 5 6 9 12 7 13]

B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

Spearman's rho = .8061

My question is what do I take away from the two comparisons as a whole? Is it possible to average them?

EDIT: I have corrected my mistake of not pairing values in both correlations. There are 10 objects in each. These ranks come from a ranked list of 30,000 names, where just the first 10 are ranked here. Though I think I now realize why I am getting different correlation results by comparing A against B and vice versa. This is because even though there are 10 ranking objects compared in each correlation, there are ranks that are contained in one list but not the other. For example, comparing A against B, there are ranks of 14 & 17 in B which are not in A and 8 & 10 in A which are not in B. This is a result of comparing a small subsample (10) of the full list (30,000), I believe.

I got to this conclusion by setting up two new list of names like so and running a Spearman's correlation when comparing A against B and vice versa:

A = [Fred, Joe, Bob, Smith, Parker, Drew, Ryan, Sarah, Danna, Mary]

B = [Joe, Fred, Parker, Drew, Ryan, Sarah, Danna, Bob, Mary, Smith]

It looks like this when comparing B against A:

A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

B = [2 1 5 6 7 8 9 3 10 4]

Spearman's rho = .4909

It look like this when comparing A against B:

A = [2 1 8 10 3 4 5 6 7 9]

B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

Spearman's rho = .4909

As one can see, Spearman's Rho is the same when comparing either way. It's just that the two list being compared must have all the same names, just in a different order. So when I compare the list of 30,000 names, it would be wise to not subsample where the two list do not contain all the same names.

Please correct anything I missed. Thanks

Comment: I'm confused by this - B and A seem to have different numbers of entries. To perform a correlation analysis you need bivariate data (so should have paired x and y values, which means you must have the same number of each).

Comment: Hi Silverfish, I updated the question to contain bivariate data. I think this helped me figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: At the moment I'm still confused, for instance *It looks like this when comparing B against A: A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10], B = [2 1 17 4 5 6 9 3 7 14], Spearman's rho = .5030.  It look like this when comparing A against B: A = [2 1 8 4 5 6 9 12 7 13], B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]. Spearman's rho = .8061*. The correlation between A and B should be the same as between B and A. Yours is not ... but I don't understand your naming of A and B. The A in your first seems to become the B in your second, while the B in your first [2, 1, 7, ...] doesn't match the [2, 1, 8...] in your second?

Comment: Refer to the edit I made. You can see there why A and B don't match up when switching comparisons but still give the same RHO value

Answer (score 1):

Correlation makes no sense at all unless there is a pairing of values, requiring therefore equal numbers of values in two variables. This simple principle applies to any kind of correlation, including Spearman correlation.

It's completely unclear to me how your unnamed software is giving you results, but they are arbitrary not to say spurious. Usually it really should not matter what software you are using for something this basic, but it does matter here what you are using and how you called it.

A related principle is that if correlation is defined then there should not be two ways to get a correlation, as there is only one valid result.

There should be suggestions about what you can do with these data, but they will depend on knowing your real aim, as it cannot, on this information, be calculating a correlation, and on knowing much more about these data and whether any of those values really are paired.

Comment: I am using matlab with this command: [RHO,PVAL] = corr(a',b','Type','Spearman'); For further clarification, this data comes from name rankings. In the two data sets, there are the same names but with different ranks. Thus comparing a against b and b against a, gives me different results.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. Some who uses MATLAB may be able to comment. My answer remains as it was. Correlation makes no sense without a unique one-to-one pairing.

Comment: Hi Nick, I updated the question and think I figured out the weird results. Thanks for your thought as it made me realize what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Pleased you sorted it out, but it's not clear that this question has long-term value for others. In essence you have realised that you misapplied Spearman and then corrected your mistake. However, I can't follow the detailed reasoning even in the edited version, so there's not an intelligible pitfall for others to learn from.

Comment: I think others can learn from this by making sure they have the same ranks in both list when they are correlating two rankings using a Spearman's Rho

Comment: I have to say that I've not encountered anyone trying otherwise.